# Link2SD: mounting /dev/block/vold/179:66 on /data/sdext2 failed: No such file or directory

Tags: external-sd, partitions, link2sd

I am using a rooted Xperia Z5 Compact E5823 with the latest stock Android 6.0 ROM.
I am trying to use a 2nd partition with Link2SD but so far I always get the same "No such file or directory"-error:

> **Mount script error**
>
> Mount script cannot be created.
>
> mount: mounting /dev/block/vold/179:66 on /data/sdext2 failed: No such file or directory

To format my microSD card I've used GParted under Debian with `ext2`, `3`, and `4`, always as primary partition. I've also used TWRP recovery to format this 2nd partition. With this I have only tried `ext3`, which my Debian recognizes as `ext2` and there seems to be no way to choose which type of partition (I suppose they have primary as default). With TWRP I could also try `ext4` but preferred to 1st post here.

I do see a `/data/sdext2` folder with help of a root file browser. This folder is empty.

The "file" `/proc/partitions` does show a `179  66  2000000  mmcblk1p2` entrance, which correspond to the second partition of my external SD card.

Link2SD has superuser permissions and its mount script `/data/data/com.buak.Link2SD/init-link2sd.sh` looks like this:

> set +e
> echo "$(date) mounting..." > $LOG
> sleep 2
> mount -t ext2 -o rw /dev/block/vold/179:66 /data/sdext2 1>>$LOG 2>>$LOG
>
> mount -t ext2 -o rw /dev/block/mmcblk1p2 /data/sdext2 1>>$LOG 2>>$LOG
>
> mount >> $LOG
> echo "$(date) mount finished" >> $LOG
> chmod 773 /data/dalvik-cache

Comment: Did you try to comment the first instance of `mount` in the script, and see if it works?

Comment: do you meam to comment `set +e` out?

Comment: No, to comment `mount -t ext2 -o rw /dev/block/vold/179:66 /data/sdext2 1>>$LOG 2>>$LOG`.

Comment: I'll try it out and let you know :)

Comment: wow! that seems to almost completely do the trick! The only unsatisfying thing is that I get a mount warning in every boot, saying that the second partition was not.mounted on boot but after so my linked apps "are not recognized by the system yet". I have then the option to Quick Reboot, Cancel, or Recreate mount scripts...

Comment: Sorry, but I never used Link2SD. You better wait for someone who's more adept at it.

Comment: ok. thanx for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was very tricky to track! It took me a while to re-address it and here is what I have found out and how to solve it.

**A little on mmcblk_p_**

1. SD cards are special about their "block-partition"-suffix, i.e. the `-blk*p*` part.
2. For the user, the numbers in the suffix `-blk*p*` are, on practical matters, determined by the system the card is mounted on.
3. Link2SD's script is sensitive to the correspondance of the microSD card's "internal" partition-suffix (`-p*`) and its "external"/"mounted" under some system. (Thus, the `No such file or directory`).

**Solution**

For Link2SD's default mount script to succeed, **you must delete and re-do the microSD card's partition table** (with GParted or similar) and then do its two (or more) partitions, the second one being an `ext2`-filesystem. 
This will yield a correspondance on the suffix-numbers `-p*` of your "second `ext2`-partition" both **in** the card and **under** the system.

**Background**

Well, I noticed that each time an SDcad gets a new partition the last index in the suffix `-blk*p_` "advances". The microSD card in question has been partitioned more that three times without resetting its partition table. That card has no "internal" `-p2` eventhough Android's kernel addresses it as such! (Tricky, huh?!) It seams that Android's kernel only takes the number of existing partitions to create the `/proc/partitions`-addresses instead of the total count of partitions ever done under an existing partition-table.

**Extra-Info**

Link2SD guarantees that your second `ext2`-partition won't be shown on your PC when you plug your device to it via USB. This is true for Windows but unfortunately not true for GNU+Linux! Windows does not recognizes `ext2`-filesystems. GNU+Linux does. As a consequence some APPs might have trouble retrieving ingormation from `/data/sdext2`.

**Finally**

Link2SD latest version at the PlayStore is 4.3.4 from 21.06.2018 and it locates its mount-script at `/data/data/com.buak.Link2SD/files`.

Also, for more information, visit [Link2SD's official site](https://link2sd.co/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use application "Apps2SD" mount a 2nd partition (after remove it and use Link2SD). (**Don't use it if you only use 1 partition is sdext2**) If you use **android 6.0** and use **both 2nd partition and "Adoptable storage"** use "Root Explorer" go to path "/etc/apps2sd-mountscript.sh" edit it. Because use 2 partition, so default it use if create is "dev/block/**mmcblk1p1** /data/sdext2", you change it to "dev/block/**mmcblk1p2** /data/sdext2" (I use Sony M4 aqua dual)

Comment: On Version new of Apps2SD you can remount ext2 by change mmcblk1p1  on dialog to mmcblk1p2 can't success so You don't edit by manual!

Comment: On Version new of Apps2SD you can remount ext2 by change mmcblk1p1 on dialog to mmcblk1p2 can success so You don't edit by manual!